# What would be a well understood opposite for "honorable mentions"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, expressions

As "honorable mentions" is defined to be

> a commendation given to a candidate in an examination or competition who is not awarded a prize.

What would be an expression used for the opposite of that? My guess would be something like "dishonorable mentions", but I haven't really heard anyone use that expression before. I assume the meaning would be understood nonetheless, but is there a commonly used variant for such an expression that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What do you mean by "opposite"  Is "winning a prize" the opposite.  Is "not winning and not being commended" the opposite?  In general, noun phrases don't have "opposites" (what is the opposite of "big dog"? "small cat"?)

Comment: By "opposite" I mean "not winning, and being mentioned in a dishonorable light", instead of "not winning, but honorably mentioned".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so rare that there no usage.

The judge may want to highlight some entries that did very well, but not quite well enough to win a prize.  Everyone else is just not mentioned.  I can't think of a situation in which a Judge says "Before I announce the winner let me mention some people who did really badly."

That would be a form of "shaming".

To "shame" someone is to make someone feel embarrassed"

> The teacher shamed Katy in front of the class by reading her essay.  She spent the rest of the day sobbing in the toilets.

Comment: The phrase [booby prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booby_prize) exists, although it is indeed rare and kind of slangy.